# Нужны ли запятые в таких деепричастных оборотах этих двух предложений?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Конструкция примерно такая:

1. В лесу, на самом краю, освещая тропинку(,) объявился сторож.
2. В лесу, на самом краю, объявился сторож(,) освещая тропинку.

Comment: Отдельный ответ давать не буду, потому что лень лезть в справочники за точными цитатами правил, но **запятые в обоих ваших предложениях стоят правильно**. В первом случае, думаю, при большом авторском желании можно счесть *освещая тропинку* наречным выражением и запятую после него не ставить. Во втором случае такая трактовка невозможна.

Comment: @Nektoid спасибо. Меня в большей степени волновал как раз первый случай, потому что столкнулся с мнением, что запятая там не нужна.

Comment: @Nektoid Как раз наоборот: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113 — пункт 7. Здесь словосочетание, а не одиночное деепричастие, но принцип тот же. Хотя нужен другой порядок слов: *сторож объявился освещая тропинку*. При этом никакого логического ударения на "объявился". В плане структуры правильно, когда деепричастие тоже выражает точечное действие (без разницы, обособлен ли оборот): *объявился [каким образом?] осветив*.

Comment: @oleedd спасибо за ссылку и дополнение ответа.